# How add event listener to Figma currentPage

Tags: typescript, dom-events, figma-api

I wrote plugin with UI for Figma using figma-api and TypeScript.
Project consist of two main files:

- `code.ts` for calling `figma-api`
- `ui.html` with `<script>...</script>` with plugin`s user interface.

My plugin is working with data of selection on current page, so I send from `code.ts` into `ui` data of for example this object:

```
figma.currentPage.selection[0]
```

How can I add event listener to `figma.currentPage`? For example, if user selected some other element on figma board, `figma.currentPage.selection` will change and I want to sent new data into `ui`.

Have you any ideas?

Comment: https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/figma/#on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the answer.

```js
figma.on('selectionchange', () => {
  console.log(figma.currentPage.selection);
});
```

https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/properties/figma-on/

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best approach but rather a quick hack that works. I am looking for the same answer but for now, I do this.

Basically, assign an initial variable layer. Then, check every few seconds for a change and if var is different from the previous var then assign a new one.

I hope that helps until we get a normal way of doing this.

```
    var selected;

    selected = figma.currentPage.selection[0];

    setInterval(() => {

      var selectedNew = figma.currentPage.selection[0];

      if (selected != selectedNew) {

        selected = selectedNew;

      }

    }, 3000)
```

Comment: yes, I also thought about it, and it seems that at the moment this is the only way to do this. but I hope it’s possible to somehow connect this with `onclick` and do without `setInterval`

Comment: Yeah you totally right. I did look at resources thats being used while running an app and it's not so bad.

Answer (score -1):

The perfect way to do it is by using

```
figma.on("selectionchange" , () => {
// insert your code here
})
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64113691/2227743).

Comment: This answer has already been given.